# Парсинг сайта под vpn

Tags: php, парсер, vpn

Необходимо парсить сайт, но проблема в том, что доступ к нему только при поднятом впн.
Скрипт будет выполняться на сервере на Debian.
Подскажите куда копать или может кто-то поделится готовым решением.

Comment: curl + proxy _(задаётся в параметрах)_. Список айпи проксей можно нагуглить.

Comment: Vpn не имеет никакого отношения к паркингу сайта, как минимум.

Comment: @NewView к не посредственному парсингу не имеет, но к получению страниц для парсинга имеет.

Comment: Это скорее настройка и адаптация к сетевому окружению, независимо от типа подключения. Правильные маршруты на уровне сети выставляются роутингом. Прокси при этом не обязательно, парсер должен работать в той среде где запущен, желательно без костылей :)

Comment: вам поможет что то типа: `route add -host 1.2.3.4 -dev vpn0` для *nix платформ. 1.2.3.4 ип адрес вашего сервера, vpn0 имя впн виртуального устройства.

Comment: ваш "сайт" не публичный? и какая проблема сообственно? опишите что вы делаете сейчас и что не выходит.

Comment: Сетевики подняли тунель до ресурса и он теперь доступен как "обычно".
Все парсится. Всем спасибо.